# Replace number pattern and email in textarea

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I want my `textarea` field to be validated in such a way that it does not contain number greater than four digits consecutively and email cannot be entered.I have been able to restrict the email but need help with the number validation. Can anyone guide me the process.
the validation which is restricting email entering in the text-area is:

```
$('#text area').change(function() {
  $(this).val( function(idx, val) {
     return val.replace(/\b(\w)+\@(\w)+\.(\w)+\b/g, "");
  });
});
```

I want help with the number validation.

Comment: Its allowing only numbers..I dont want that..I want numbers alphabets all to be allowed but numbers only of length 4 chars.

Comment: Why are you removing the email address, rather than flagging it as invalid and letting the user correct it?

Comment: I am not wanting to allow email addresses,so am replacing it with a space,okk i will do that.

Comment: @Vicks so you want to allow "ui1234kk99" but not allow "ui12345kk99"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, not that `#text area` is not a valid ID, and also, the change event will not apply when you cut or copy/paste for example. This will remove digits of length 4 and valid email address (among other things that don't hurt)

```
$('#example').on('input propertychange', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\d{4,}|\S+@\S+\.\S+/g,''));
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xghqnf5o/4/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,i was just trying but i got you.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=\d{1,4}$)^\d+$
```

This should validate for only 4 digits.You can club your email regex with this.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/14

Edit.

Use

```
(?!\b(?:\w)+\@(?:\w)+\.(?:\w)+\b)(?=\d{1,4}$)(^\d+$)
```

See demo

http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/18

Comment: please can you elaborate I am not understanding your demo,on how is it working.

Comment: it uses positive lookahead.says that form start of string to end there can only be intergers and that too from 1 to 4.

Comment: I cannot put the regex  in the function can you help.?

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go and let you know.

Comment: @Vicks try the new one.

Comment: Okk i will implement it